# p5.js Fetch API failing when using Microsoft Edge Tools for VS Code on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, microsoft-edge, p5.js

Is there an issue with Microsoft Edge Tools for VS Code, not working properly with p5.js and when running on a Mac?

I am receiving errors with the p5.js Fetch API, that the URL Scheme "file" is not supported.  What does that mean?  If I run the same using Live Server, and run the web page in an external browser like Chrome or Firefox, I don't get that error, and the JS Code executes fine.

Anyone know what's causing this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you please provide a minimal code example for us to reproduce this issue?